# calling JQuery after PHP script loaded

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Basically I want to perform this check:

```
   var done = "<?= $test_details['done_test'] ?>";
    if(typeof done == 'undefined'){
    $('WORKING').appendTo('#bodyArea'); // just for testing (code here)
    }
```

Obviously the check is using a value from an SQL query. So, what I want to do and cant seem to get working is:

on loading page: run query with PHP then run the JQuery which checks result value from query is not NULL.

this is what I have tried:

```
$(window).load(function () {
 // code here
});
```

and:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // code here
});
```

no luck with both.

Many thanks for help.

Comment: javascript is always executed after php, since php runs on the server it's executed even before the page is sent to the browser. then (in the browser) the javascript is executed. so both your versions should work. what does the sourcecode for "var done = ..." look like in the browser? also done will never be undefined but an empty string at most (if the php $test_details is empty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var done = "<?= $test_details['done_test'] ?>";
if(typeof done == 'undefined'){
   $('WORKING').appendTo('#bodyArea'); // just for testing (code here)
}
```

`typeof done` would never be undefined since you'd always be defining it.

If you want to run some jquery based on your PHP, you can try this

```
<?php if (empty($test_details['done_test'])) : ?>
   <script type='text/javascript'>
       //Code runs ONLY if $test_details['done_test'] is empty
       $(document).ready(function(){
         $('WORKING').appendTo('#bodyArea'); // just for testing (code here)
       });
   </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This way, the check is done on a PHP variable with PHP. When the page is processed, if the variable is empty PHP will output the JS making it run.

**DEBUGGING**

If you're still having problems, put the code below and see what happens

```
<?php if (empty($test_details['done_test'])) : ?>
   <script type='text/javascript'>
       alert("$test_details['done_test'] is empty");
   </script>
<?php else : ?>
   <script type='text/javascript'>
       alert("$test_details['done_test'] is not empty");
   </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you're not getting any output, then you're doing something wrong. We'll have to see your HTML.

If your getting that `$test_details['done_test'] is not empty` message, then that means your earlier code was working properly because it was not executing *if the variable was not empty*

Comment: You can put it in the head. Make sure you wrap that code in `$(document).ready()`. Not sure about the highligher, but the code is fine. _Make sure you aren't putting it in the middle of another `<script>` tag_

Comment: it doesnt appear to do anything, I get no output.

Comment: this is what im trying: `$(document).ready(function () {
       $('WORKING').appendTo('#bodyArea'); // just for testing (code here)
    }`

Comment: I updated the answer. Check the updated code as well as the debugging note I added